# Bypass double quotes inside XML value

Tags: sql-server, xml

Check @lptr's comment for solution

I have this piece of XML from which I need to extract the values and ids using SQL Server:

```
<root>
    <field id="1" value="gfjsdgfdjy duahsd "absdjsd"" />
    <field id="37" value="ysgfdyua" />
    <field id="13" value="asdas" />
    <field id="73" value="fgdgfd" />
    <field id="adsf" value="fdsa" />
</root>
```

This is what I use to extract the values and ids from that XML, which is stored into variable @test, and insert them into a temp table:

```
insert into @tmp (field, val) 
select field.value('@id', 'nvarchar(100)') as fieldID,
       field.value('@value', 'nvarchar(200)') as val
from @test.nodes('root/field') A(field)
```

That query works fine until there's a value that has double quotes like in the example above, which throws the followig error: XML parsing: line 1, character 108, whitespace expected

Any way of working around that?

I have to mention that I do not create these XMLs by hand, but get them from a DB, so any mistakes in their creation is not my fault.

Comment: Well, that's not valid XML. Whatever process is creating them is doing it wrong. The first `field` element should be using `&quot;` instead of `"` characters in the attribute value: `<field id="1" value="gfjsdgfdjy duahsd &quot;absdjsd&quot;" />`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I've searched and tried replacing the quotes with "&quot" to see if something changes, but i get the same result. The "&quot" gets replaced with " in the field (which has XML AS data type) where the xml is stored.

Comment: Note that the semicolon is required, `&quot;`. I don't think this is something you can fix with a simple search-and-replace, given that quote characters themselves are used to delimit attribute values.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yup, I made sure to use semicolon with &quot. But it seems, as you've said, that the values were not correctly stored from the beginning and I think I'll have to address these cases one by one. Ty for your time!

Comment: best-effort, split the xml parser error message, get the position of the erroneous character and escape it.. https://dbfiddle.uk/gCXRrds4

Comment: @lptr You're a savior! After a bit of adaptation it works perfectly. Please post that as an answer so I can mark it. I have one question, if you don't mind, why is the @i iterating to 50 specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Conformant XML parsers are *required* to report all well-formedness errors, so any conformant XML parser will reject this ill-formed XML.

You can sometimes get around this by using parsers (which are not conformant XML parsers) that attempt to repair errors. However, I don't know if any of them are capable of handling this particular problem, Note that in the general case it can't be detected, consider

```
<root>
    <field id="1" value="some " inner  " 3" />
    <field id="2" value="some " inner= " 3" />
</root>
```

The second field is well-formed XML.

Whenever a supplier provides you with ill-formed XML, you need to complain, as you would with any other product defect. Usually I have found suppliers very responsive to such error reports. It's surprising how often the XML export capability was entrusted to some junior programmer with no XML knowledge or experience, even if the company concerned is a very professional outfit.

Comment: Thanks for the support! Indeed, working with XMLs  with little to no experience is not the best idea, especially when you have to import data from an old DB to a new one. But everybody has to start somewhere.